# CMake: linking library on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, dll, cmake

Im trying to make CMakeklist.txt file on Windows and I have big problem.

I wrote

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.2)

project(c_api)

set(INC_PATH target/release/deps)
set(PROJECT_DLL traffic.dll)
set(PROJECT_LIB traffic.dll.lib)

configure_file(${INC_PATH}/${PROJECT_DLL} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} COPYONLY)
include_directories(${INC_PATH}/include)
add_library(traffic UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET traffic PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_DLL})
set_property(TARGET traffic PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_LIB})

file(GLOB SOURCES "c_api/examples/ai_module/*.c")
add_executable(ai_module
${SOURCES}
)
target_link_libraries(ai_module traffic )
```

I run the project that CMake generate i got

`LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2D8`

I thought that the problem is `add_library(traffic UNKNOWN IMPORTED)` but if I change it to `add_library(traffic SHARED IMPORTED)` I get

`LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _traffic_import_osm referenced in function _main    ai_module`

so I assume that Visual Studio dont see a library.

I run this code on linux and i only change the `.dll` format for `.so` and it works fine.

Im using Visual Studio 15 2017 on CMake

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation of your first error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h6ctxtk(v=vs.100).aspx), it appears you are trying to link to the .dll directly. On Windows, shared libraries require two files. The shared .dll, which includes all the definitions of the functions and classes in the library, and the .lib which (when build with the dll) only contains the declarations. The stub .lib file is used at compile time to tell the linker what to expect from the function.

Do you have both the .lib and the .dll? If you do not have the .lib, you cannot link the .dll to your program.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. CMake make project of 32bits and my .dll is 64bit and now its work